# How to extract a specific string followed by any number?

Tags: r

I have a small problem. 
I have text in this format:

```
A.1 Goals

Section 1: Blah Blah Blah
Random sentence A. Random sentence.
Section 2: Blah Blah Blah
Random sentence A.
Random sentence.

A.2 description
```

I want to obtain output of:

```
A.1 Goals

Section 1: Blah Blah Blah

Section 2: Blah Blah Blah

A.2 description
```

So basically how to obtain any string that is repeated more than once and followed by any possible number (any pattern of the same string and varying numbers)

Comment: My bad, I accidently did that. It should be A.2 description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grep` after reading with `readLines`.  Here, we match either 
the letter ("A" followed by a `.` followed by one or more numbers - `\\d+`) or (`|`) if the text starts with "Section" (`^Section`) followed by some characters (`.*`) and if there is a repeated word followed spaces (`(\\w+\\s*)\\1` - `\\1` is the backreference for the captured group)

```
out <- grep("(^A\\.\\d+)|(^Section.*\\b(\\w+\\s*)\\1)", lines, value = TRUE)
cat(out, sep= "\n\n")
#A.1 Goals

#Section 1: Blah Blah Blah

#Section 2: Blah Blah Blah

#A.2 description
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt") #reading from the file
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it any string? This does address A. and Section, but would it be possible to generalize it further?

Comment: @J.Doe If the Section starts with any LETTER, you can use `(^[A-Z]\\.\\d+)` and I assume you have `Section` as stattic

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you by any chance know how I would get the first sentence after "Section 1: Blah Blah blah", so "Random Sentence A."

Comment: @J.Doe  I think the other solution updated with the request you raised

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, However I am not sure about the exact output:

```
string <- c("Section 1: Blah Blah Blah","Random sentence A. Random sentence.",
"Section 2: Blah Blah Blah","Random sentence A.",
"Random sentence.")

 grep("(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\s+\\1",string, value=TRUE)
```

**Logic**: The word is wrapped under parenthesis to capture it, then it can be captured into `\\1` to get the repetition. Taking two instances of `\\1` suggest we want to select it more than twice.

I am assuming the similar structure that , the word must be followed by a space then the word.

**Output**:

```
[1] "Section 1: Blah Blah Blah" "Section 2: Blah Blah Blah"
```

---

**Added after OP Request**:

With `invert = TRUE` in `grep`, you can change the matching

```
 grep("(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\s+\\1",string, value=TRUE,invert = TRUE)
```

Hence above regex would result to :

```
#[1] "Random sentence A. Random sentence."
#[2] "Random sentence A."                 
#[3] "Random sentence."
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how I would get the first sentence after "Section 1: Blah Blah Blah" and "Section 2: Blah Blah Blah", generically, so basically both "Random Sentence A."